Existence of k-complete uniform ultrafilter over a regular cardinal, k is strongly compact
This is a question about set theory. Let $\kappa\leq \lambda$ be infinite cardinals such that $\kappa$ is strongly compact and $\lambda$ is regular. My question is: how to construct a $\kappa$-complete uniform ultrafilter over $\lambda$?
I try to construct such an ultrafilter as follows. $\lbrace X\subseteq\lambda\mid\vert\lambda\setminus X\vert<\lambda\rbrace$ is an uniform and $\lambda$-complete filter, and hence is also $\kappa$-complete. Since $\kappa$ is strongly compact, the filter can be extended into a $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter over $\lambda$. But is the new filter also uniform? Or, is there any other method to solve this problem? Thanks for any comments or suggestions.

The new filter (the ultrafilter in the question) is uniform because of your old (non-ultra)filter. If a  subset $Y$ of $\lambda$ has cardinality $<\lambda$, then its complement is in the old filter, hence also in the new one. Since a filter can't contain a set and its complement, $Y$ cannot be in the new filter.

Suppose that $\kappa$ is $\lambda$-strongly compact and $\lambda$ is regular. Let $j:V\to M$ be the ultrapower by a fine measure $\mu$ on $P_\kappa\lambda$. The object $s=[\text{id}]_\mu$ in $M$ is a subset of $j(\lambda)$ of size less than $j(\kappa)$, hence bounded, and $j"\lambda\subseteq s$ by fineness. So $\sup j"\lambda<j(\lambda)$. Let $\delta$ be any ordinal in that interval, and define $U$ for $X\subseteq\lambda$ by
$$X\in U\quad\iff\quad \delta\in j(X).$$
This is a $\kappa$ complete ultrafilter on $\lambda$ in $V$. It is uniform, since every small subset of $\lambda$ is bounded and therefore its image is contained in some $j(\alpha)$, whereas $\delta$ exceeds $\sup j"\lambda$. So every set in $U$ is unbounded in $\lambda$.
By the way, the truly interesting question is the converse direction. Namely, it is a theorem of Ketonen that if a cardinal $\kappa$ admits $\kappa$-complete uniform ultrafilters on every regular $\lambda\geq\kappa$, then $\kappa$ is strongly compact. I've given above the easy direction of the biconditional, for it is the converse direction that is Ketonen's fundamental contribution.

Joel has given an answer based on a modern view of strong compactness in terms of elementary embeddings. I'd  like to complement that with an answer based on the oldest view of strong compactness of $\kappa$: The infinitary logic $L_{\kappa,\kappa}$ has the compactness property that, for any set $S$ of sentences, if each subset of $S$ of cardinality $<\kappa$ is satisfiable, then  $S$ itself is satisfiable. In fact, this compactness property is needed only for the propositional fragment of $L_{\kappa,\kappa}$ (which I suppose should be called $L_{\kappa,1}$).
Work with a vocabulary that has propositional symbols (= 0-ary predicate symbols) $\hat X$, one for each subset $X$ of $\lambda$. Let $S$ consist of the following sentences of $L_{\kappa,1}$:
$$\widehat{\bigcap_{i\in I}X_i}\iff\bigwedge_{i\in I}\widehat{X_i}$$ for each family $\{X_i:i\in I\}$ of subsets of $\lambda$ where the index set $I$ has cardinality $<\kappa$,
$$ \widehat{\lambda-X}\iff\neg\hat X$$  for each $X\subseteq\lambda$,
and
$$\neg\hat Y$$
for every subset of $\lambda$ of cardinality $<\lambda$.
I claim that, if this set  $S$ is satisfiable, say by a truth assignment $v$, then
$$
\mathcal U=\{X\subseteq\lambda:v(\hat X)=\mathtt{true}\}
$$
is a $\kappa$-complete uniform ultrafilter on $\lambda$. Indeed, $\mathcal U$ contains $\lambda$ by the first batch of sentences in $S$ (take $I=\varnothing$), is closed under supersets (take $I=\{0,1\}$ with $X_0\subseteq X_1$), and is closed under intersections of $<\kappa$ sets (take the $X_i$ to be the sets you want to intersect). So $\mathcal U$ is a $\kappa$-complete filter on $\lambda$. It is an ultrafilter by the second batch of sentences in $S$. Finally, it is uniform by the third batch of sentences. So, if $S$ is satisfiable then $\mathcal U$ is as desired.
By strong compactness of $\kappa$, it suffices to show that each subset $S_0\subseteq S$ of cardinality $<\kappa$ is satisfiable. Fix such an $S_0$ and let $B$ be the union of all the $Y$'s such that $\neg\hat Y$ is in $S_0$. Since each such $Y$ has cardinality $<\lambda$, since there are $<\kappa\leq\lambda$ such $Y$'s, and since $\lambda$ is regular, $B$ cannot be all of $\lambda$. Let $\alpha$ be any member of $\lambda-B$ and define a truth assignment $v$ by setting, for each $X\subseteq\lambda$,
$$
v(\hat X)=\mathtt{true} \iff \alpha\in X.
$$
The first two batches of sentences in $S_0$ (in fact in all of $S$) are trivially satisfied by $v$. The third batch of sentences in $S_0$ are satisfied because $\alpha\notin B$, i.e., $\alpha\notin Y$ for any $Y$ such that $(\neg\hat Y)\in S_0$.
